# How to hide columns with PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to hide columns with getColumnDimension('A')->setVisible(false) for example, but the hidden columns can be visible when I unfold the hidden columns. So the columns are not realy hidden. Is there an other way to hide column. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you use this option to hide you only hide one column but the given column like A will be replaced by B.
You can use

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->removeColumnByIndex(1);
```

or

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(0);
```

to get rid of that column.